# IF condition in trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012

I converting this Oracle trigger to SQL Server. In Oracle there are using if condition for updating a table. I was wondering is it necessary to use if statement in SQL Server. I'm thinking to use in where clause. Please let me know if that's correct?

Thanks

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "DB1"."TG_PG_CODES"
   BEFORE UPDATE OF "str_number", "op_status"
   ON "DB1"."Header_T"
   REFERENCING OLD AS oldrow NEW AS newrow
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
   IF :newrow.op_status = 'X'
   THEN
   UPDATE DB1.pg_pollutant
   SET op_status = 'X',
         str_comp_status = '98',
         str_mod_person = '3327'
   WHERE str_number = :newrow.str_number;
   END IF;

   IF     :newrow.op_status <> 'X'
   AND SUBSTR (:oldrow.str_pgcodes, 1, 1) = '1'
   AND SUBSTR (:newrow.str_pgcodes, 1, 1) = '0'
   THEN
   UPDATE DB1.pg_pollutant
     SET op_status = 'X',
         str_comp_status = '98'
   WHERE str_number = :newrow.str_number
   AND str_pollutant_key = :newrow.str_number || '0';
   END IF;
   END;

 =============================================
 In sql server

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TG_TG_PG_CODES] ON [dbo].[Header_T]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
 IF(UPDATE(str_number)
    OR UPDATE(op_status))
     BEGIN
         IF(
           (
               SELECT op_status
               FROM inserted
           ) = 'X')
             BEGIN
                 UPDATE a
                   SET
                       a.op_status = 'X',
                       a.str_comp_status = '98',
                       a.str_mod_person = '3327'
                 FROM DB1.pg_pollutant a
                      INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON a.str_number = i.str_number;
             END;
         UPDATE a
           SET
               a.op_status = 'X',
               a.str_comp_status = '98'
         FROM DB1.pg_pollutant a
              INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON a.[str_number] = i.[str_number]
                                          AND a.str_pollutant_key = i.[str_number]+'0'
              INNER JOIN Deleted AS d ON a.[str_number] = d.[str_number]
         WHERE i.stroperationalstatus <> 'X'
               AND SUBSTRING(d.str_pgcodes, 1, 1) = '1'
               AND SUBSTRING(i.str_pgcodes, 1, 1) = '0'; /* I used this condition in where clause */
     END;
```

Comment: The biggest change will be that SQL Server doesn't have `FOR EACH ROW` and no `BEFORE UPDATE` triggers. Your SQL Server trigger will be called only **once** per statement - even if that statement updates 25 rows at once. In SQL Server, in that case, your `Inserted` pseudo table inside the trigger will contain **25 rows** so you need to write your trigger in a properly set-based manner to account for that

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for your response. What do you mean by set based manner ? I didn't get.

Comment: You cannot do something like `DECLARE @ID INT; SELECT @ID = Id FROM Inserted;` because there *will be* multiple rows in the `Inserted` table - you have to work with the data **as a set**